# T-SQL: Update column only if value is provided

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Currently I have this `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Customer 
SET Name = @Name,
    Age = @Age,
    Email = @Email
    ...
```

Now I need to include column into the `UPDATE` statement only if value is provided. Otherwise, do not include the column in the `UPDATE` statement.

So conceptually probably something like this:

```
UPDATE Customer 
SET
    IF LEN(@Name) > 0 THEN Name = @Name,
    IF LEN(@Age) > 0 THEN Age = @Age,
    IF LEN(@Email ) > 0 THEN Email = @Email
    ...
```

Is there any way can achieve this? I'm thinking about dynamic query but the list of update columns are super long, so tons of work need to be done to change to dynamic query like this:

```
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE Customer SET '

IF LEN(@Name) > 0
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'Name = @Name,'

IF LEN(@Age) > 0
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'Age= @Age,'
```

Comment: If "missing" values are nulls then you can use `... set Name = Coalesce( @Name, Name ), Age = Coalesce( @Age, Age ), ...`. That doesn't work as well if you need to be able to set column values to null.

Comment: Unfortunately dynamic SQL is the optimal way to do this. It's less readable but its your best shot. Triggers that check for specific updated columns will be triggered if you update a column to it's own value `(UPDATE T SET Name = T.Name)`, so skipping the updated column will improve performance in this case. Be very careful of the **variable's scope** when using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should try this 
(after declaring and setting your variables @Name, @Age and @Email )

```
    UPDATE Customer SET
    Name = case when @Name  is null then Name  else @Name  end,
    Age  = case when @Age   is null then Age   else @Age   end,
    Email= case when @Email is null then Email else @Email end,
    ...
```

if any of the variables has a null value it will not update the field.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this...

```
UPDATE Customer SET
    [Name] = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Name, '') = '' THEN [Name] ELSE @Name END
    ,Age = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Age, '') = '' THEN Age ELSE @Age END
    ,Email = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Email, '') = '' THEN Email ELSE @Email END
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If your missing values are null:

```
UPDATE [Customer] SET
    [Name] = COALESCE(@Name, [Name]),
    [Age] = COALESCE(@Age, [Age]),
    [Email] = COALESCE(@Email, [Email]),
    ...
```

If they're blank, then you can use `NULLIF` to cast to null, which has the potential added benefit of treating empty strings the same as nulls:

```
UPDATE [Customer] SET
    [Name] = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Name, ''), [Name]),
    [Age] = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Age, ''), [Age]),
    [Email] = COALESCE(NULLIF(@Email, ''), [Email]),
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
UPDATE Customer SET
    [Name] = ISNULL(@Name, [Name])
    ,Age = ISNULL(@Age, Age)
    ,Email = ISNULL(@Email, Email)
...
```

It is a shorthand query of checking NULL value in update.